# Slick slider, при синхронизированных слайдах не работают кастомные кнопки

Tags: slider-slick.js

Столкнулся со страной проблемой.
Есть slick slider синхронизированный.
У него заданы кастомные стрелки

```
  $('.room_slider_for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.room_slider_nav'

  });
  $('.room_slider_nav').slick({
    infinite: true,
    dots: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.room_slider_for',
    prevArrow: $('.room_slider_prev'),
    nextArrow: $('.room_slider_next')
  });
```

`
И при нажатии на стрелку кастомную, срабатывает прокрутка только нижнего слайдера, верхний не реагирует.
Если включить дефолтные кнопки, то там всё нормально. В каком месте я не прав?

Comment: наверное надо стрелки добавить в верхний слайдер, раз вы хотите что бы верхний крутился

Comment: Это синхронизированный слайдер, в этом и смысл, что верхний одно большое фото, и нижний слайдер повторение верхнего только из большего количества элементов.

Comment: тогда дополните свой вопрос, пока не понятно, какого результата вы ожидаете

Comment: Если начать всё сначала. Есть табы, в них синхронизированные слайдеры. 
Было 2 пути. При переключении табов, слайдеры просто не показывались, приходилось нажимать стрелочки. В таком случае слайдер работает как надо.
И второй путь, slick("reinit"). В таком случае, слайдер не работает,как надо, но зато при нажатии на таб,слайдер сразу виден.